# What does this line mean and how to change it in order to make it work on linux?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I'm learning some of OCR and I found this pretty exercise in this web

https://medium.com/programming-fever/license-plate-recognition-using-opencv-python-7611f85cdd6c

now the problem is that when I try to run it on muy ubuntu 18.04, I got a "file not found" error, here is the line that im struggling with

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
```

I would love if any of you can explain me what does this line do? Also do I need to change it to "/home/user/" ? Where can I find the equivalent file in ubuntu? Thanks in advance

Comment: This line tells pytesseract where to look for the executable in Windows. Usually in Linux, I find I do not have to provide this line at all. You can try commenting it out and see if your script works. However, if you happened to install tesseract locally for just one user, you may have to supply the path for the executable in Linux somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line in question is giving the shell command for running an executable. In this case, it's a windows exec, so you will need to find the Linux equivalent. Linux execs tend to not be named in the same way.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but there  is an equivalent for linux?  or it is instaled when i install tesseract by pip?

Comment: you can find it here: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/master/Home.md
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
sudo apt install libtesseract-dev